# jQuery slideToggle overlaps previous content on sliding

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

i'm trying to use jQuery slideToggle() function to show and hide a table with some details.
the idea is that when i click on a table's title row, i get the details below.

i'm using a code from w3 school, this is the original:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_slide_toggle

the problem is that the sliding div overlaps the already existing table headers.
look at the results of running the code here:
`http://62.219.127.85/sites/isell/tests/123123.php`

I use the  `onmouseover()` in order to get the header I currently going to click.
here's my code (only an example I wrote, not the real one)

can anyone please find what's wrong here?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
#hideme,#triggerSlide
{
padding:5px;
text-align:center;
background-color:#e5eecc;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
#hideme
{
padding:50px;
display:none;
}
</style>

<body>
<div id="triggerSlide" class="adID" onmouseover="storeAdID(this);" 
style="padding:2px;">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">asdasd</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>


<div class="adID" id="hideme">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>145</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>987</td>
            <td>951</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>

<script> 
    var adID;

    function storeAdID(obj) {
        adID = obj.className;
    }
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#triggerSlide").click(function(){
    $("."+adID).slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two elements with the class "adID" and you are hiding them both.

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mmcglynn/j6z73/

I think your want something closer to this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
#hideme,#triggerSlide
{
padding:5px;
text-align:center;
background-color:#e5eecc;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
#hideme
{
padding:50px;
display:none;
}
</style>

<body>
<div id="triggerSlide" style="padding:2px;cursor:pointer">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">asdasd</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>


<div class="adID" id="hideme">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>145</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>987</td>
            <td>951</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#triggerSlide").click(function(){
    $(".adID").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: see the problem... now it works in the small example..
but when I take it to the "real world",  it only works with the first table, but not with the others...
here is the full code:  http://codeviewer.org/view/code:29da

@mmcglynn , can you please take a look?

Comment: @DanielBriskman Can you make a fiddle with an example from your code you linked above.

Comment: sorry, but what's a fiddle? :)

Comment: ok, i have managed to get it working ... but:
after i click, the panel goes down, back up and down again.
same happens when trying to fold, it goes up, down, and up again.
any ideas about *that* ?
here's the latest code:  'http://codeviewer.org/view/code:29dd'

Comment: The code you are showing is PHP - it's probably better to show the rendered code. Also, the changes I suggest are not reflected in your new example.

Comment: I added a fiddle to my answer.

Comment: here is the fiddle... 'http://jsfiddle.net/brdaniel12/fdgEh/'
i looked at your suggestions and made it a bit different, i still need the id and class for both divs, because i get them from a database.
but it works now, it changes only the selected row, but make it bounce back and forth...

Comment: you've got it :) if you can also take a look at what happens now...
here's a video of what goes there:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17289984/SRFile2012_9_18_17_30_57_226.avi